# to Calculate the capacity of Voltage Stabilizer required for Home use

Tags: low-voltage

wanted to calculate the capacity of a voltage stabilizer for home use, Refrigerator has its own inbuilt voltage stabilizer, please tell me shall i have to include the refrigerator to calculate the capacity of voltage stabilizer for complete home via main line single phase.

Comment: Where on this planet are you located?  Electrical systems can vary greatly by country.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. As @Tyson noted, you'll need to provide a lot more information before we can help you.

Comment: I stay in  Navi Mumbai, India